# Cohomology of $\mathcal O_X$ for toric varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, toric-geometry

Motivated by my ignorance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12767/cohomological-decomposition-of-tensor-sheaves/12774#12774), if $X$ is a projective toric variety, is 
$$H^m(X, \mathcal O_X) \cong 
\begin{cases}
0 & m > 0 \\
\mathbb C & m = 1
\end{cases}
$$
as for $\mathbb P^n$?

Comment: I take it $H^m$ means dimension of m-th cohomology?

Comment: Whoops, I fixed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is true, at least for varieties over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.  Indeed, a toric variety over an algebraically closed field is rational (i.e., birational to projective space).  In characteristic zero, rational connectedness is a birational invariant, so toric varieties are rationally connected.  Finally, any rationally connected variety is $\mathcal{O}$-acyclic, which is the name for the conclusion that you want.  See e.g. [here](http://www.aimath.org/WWN/qptsurface2/articles/html/14a/) for this last implication.

The conclusion might well hold more generally; I am not an expert in these matters.  You may want to ask your question on MathOverflow if you are not satisfied with this answer.

Comment: It's true in finite characteristic as well. See section 3.5 in Fulton's "Toric Varieties" book for how to compute cohomology of line bundles on toric varieties over any field. I don't think he singles out the case of the trivial line bundle; but it is easy to plug it in and see that you get 0.

Comment: Alternatively, one uses that the Hodge numbers $h^{p,0}$ are birational invariants. (I hope this comment might be useful to someone some day. Your answer definitely was useful for me.)